# Minecraft server fails to open

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server, windows-10

Whenever I try to launch a vanilla Minecraft server, either by double-clicking the JAR or by executing it via PowerShell / Command Prompt, I keep getting the same error:

```
[12:00:25] [main/ERROR]: Errors with built-in recipes!
[12:00:25] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.12.2
[12:00:25] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[12:00:25] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[12:00:25] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[12:00:25] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
[12:00:25] [Server thread/INFO]: Using default channel type
[12:00:25] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing level "world"
[12:00:25] [Server thread/ERROR]: Encountered an unexpected exception
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
        at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.ensureFile(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:96) ~[zipfs.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:110) ~[zipfs.jar:1.8.0_151]
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at ns.a(SourceFile:133) ~[minecraft_server.1.12.2.jar:?]
        at ns.a(SourceFile:73) ~[minecraft_server.1.12.2.jar:?]
        at ns.<init>(SourceFile:66) ~[minecraft_server.1.12.2.jar:?]
        at oo.b(SourceFile:164) ~[minecraft_server.1.12.2.jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:281) ~[minecraft_server.1.12.2.jar:?]
        at nz.j(SourceFile:233) ~[minecraft_server.1.12.2.jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:434) [minecraft_server.1.12.2.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
[12:00:25] [Server thread/ERROR]: This crash report has been saved to: C:\Users\avi12\OneDrive\Documents\WebStorm\Minecraft server.properties Generator\Minecraft server\.\crash-reports\crash-2017-11-04_12.00.25-server.txt
[12:00:25] [Server thread/INFO]: Stopping server
[12:00:25] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving players
[12:00:25] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving worlds
[12:00:25] [Server Shutdown Thread/INFO]: Stopping server
[12:00:25] [Server Shutdown Thread/INFO]: Saving players
```

A few notes:

- My Java is up-to-date.
- The command to start the server using PowerShell was `java -jar .\minecr aft_server.1.12.2.jar nogui`.
- Below is a list of the contents of a former, working server:

  [image]
- [Here](https://pastebin.com/scv2H10k) is a crash report ("*crash-2017-11-04_12.00.25-server.txt*") mentioned in the warning.

Comment: We need more info, what kind to server? Vanilla or Spigot? What Minecraft version? Plugins?

Comment: I'm out of ideas, `Errors with built-in recipes!` usually pops up during recipe making (in modded of course) but your server is vanilla; I have no idea why `UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown during server startup either. Maybe, a wild guess, it's the generator that's causing the issue??

Comment: No. The generator is a JavaScript software that I'm working on. A part of it is an MOTD generator, and for this part, I'm trying to make the generator as close as possible to look like a real MOTD, which is why I attempted to open a server - so I can easily control the MOTD and compare it to my software.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I asked for help in StackExchange's gaming site because I thought that maybe professional people would be able to help. I could equally post this exact post in Minecraft Forum, except - I'm not sure if anyone would actually be able to help there.

Comment: @avi12 I know this is an old post, but I'm curious: are you still running your own mc server on windows this way?

Comment: If I set up a server, I use a batch file that allocates additional RAM, so the server will most likely not run out of RAM. Plus, I give the argument `nogui`

Comment: I know this is an old post, but did you try reporting to mojang

Answer (score 1):

The error in your message seems to involve an invalid zip file. Check if your resource or behaviour pack is valid (for the right version) and is not corrupted.

Also check if your resource/behaviour pack is not unpacked.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have set all your files up correctly. Download `minecraft_server.1.12.2.jar` from the [official webpage](https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/server) and put it in its own folder.

Rather than using a command to run your server, I would recommend using a `.bat` file for consistency, as well as to facilitate the spotting of errors.

Open Notepad (or any other text editor) and paste this in:

```
java -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -jar minecraft_server.1.12.2.jar nogui
pause
```

Then go to File > Save As and rename the file to `start_server.bat`. Remember to change the drop down box from `Text File` to `All files`.

Double click to run the batch file and the server should run.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I executed this command via PowerShell. Unfortunately, the same error occurs.

Comment: @avi12, I'm afraid I'm unsure then